# I want to create a simple JAX_RS web application in JAVA for Only Mail Sending Mails?

Tags: java, email, jax-rs

I am trying to create a simple project to send emails by using JAX_RS webservice.My Project Structure is below i am attaching the image.
[image]
I added two jar file activation.jar and javax.mail.jar below i am showing the screen shot of this two jars.[image]

My code also i am attaching below.

```
package org.jboss.tools.examples.util;

import java.util.Properties;

 import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
 import javax.mail.Session;
 import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

 public class SendMailTLS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "yarammadanmohan@gmail.com";
    final String password = "********";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new    InternetAddress("yarammadanmohan@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("madanmohan4b9@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
 }
```

I am running this code as Run as Java Application.I don't know where i am doing mistake can any body help me.In below i will show my error also.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:               javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtIy
   534-5.7.14  3maNrYo4kaDb2rc5erk2pei43_q2e7kyJ1JIbLFHs477w_X06vuOSboRxaYk4L5kmgoE4c
   534-5.7.14 PodLr5JoXlmctqLyRbb6shVTnQBfRVE-lIwwPWzUB0YlhiWyve2ZmkElFxWLeBD0HHqyDU
   534-5.7.14 W56ghGj4q5ElJ_CiVeCW7SO97g4aICDdZ5uD6e-XegeF3XymUzi4mdJsO1CPHETdA5nT6A
   534-5.7.14 uCOIS-lVTP3m8blzkP3H6U6sIqvQ> Please log in via your web browser and
   534-5.7.14 then try again.
   534-5.7.14  Learn more at
   534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754  db8sm15863413pad.43 - gsmtp

   at org.jboss.tools.examples.util.SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:48)
   Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14   <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtIy
   534-5.7.14 3maNrYo4kaDb2rc5erk2pei43_q2e7kyJ1JIbLFHs477w_X06vuOSboRxaYk4L5kmgoE4c
   534-5.7.14 PodLr5JoXlmctqLyRbb6shVTnQBfRVE-lIwwPWzUB0YlhiWyve2ZmkElFxWLeBD0HHqyDU
   534-5.7.14 W56ghGj4q5ElJ_CiVeCW7SO97g4aICDdZ5uD6e-XegeF3XymUzi4mdJsO1CPHETdA5nT6A
   534-5.7.14 uCOIS-lVTP3m8blzkP3H6U6sIqvQ> Please log in via your web browser and
   534-5.7.14 then try again.
   534-5.7.14  Learn more at
   534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 db8sm15863413pad.43 - gsmtp

   at c om.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:893)
   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
  at    org.jboss.tools.examples.util.SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:43)
```

Thanks in Advance,
MadanMohan

Answer (score 0):

I use the code from Google:

```
   /**
 * Send email using GMail SMTP server.
 *
 * @param username GMail username
 * @param password GMail password
 * @param recipientEmail TO recipient
 * @param ccEmail CC recipient. Can be empty if there is no CC recipient
 * @param title title of the message
 * @param message message to be sent
 * @throws AddressException if the email address parse failed
 * @throws MessagingException if the connection is dead or not in the connected state or if the message is not a MimeMessage
 */
public static void Send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

    /*
    If set to false, the QUIT command is sent and the connection is immediately closed. If set 
    to true (the default), causes the transport to wait for the response to the QUIT command.

    ref :   http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html
            http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5205249
            smtpsend.java - demo program from javamail
    */
    props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    // -- Create a new message --
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "@gmail.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

    if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
    }

    msg.setSubject(title);
    msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());      
    t.close();
}
```

Also try ports 587 or 465